# How does Oneness Pentecostalism interpret Matthew 24:36?

Tags: exegesis, nature-of-god, gospel-of-matthew, oneness-pentecostalism

Matthew 24:36 (NIV)

> 36“But about that day or hour no one knows, not even the angels in heaven, **nor the Son, but only the Father.**

If the Father and the Son are expressions of the same God, how come the Son does not know "the day or hour" but the Father does?